# php getting the name of the class

Tags: php, oop

Is there a way for a class called inside another to know the name of the outer class?

Example:

```
class A{
  // need to get the name of B
  // some stuff
}

class B{
  $var = new A;
}
```

[get_parent_class()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php) qon't do the work since B is not a child of A.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Sorry everyone I had to change the question. What I wanted to ask is can class A know the name of the class in which it is being called. Again sorry for idiotic first question.

Comment: Since there seems to be some confusion over what you are trying to do, please refine the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, it's impossible.

Well, almost. You could hack your way to the calling class from [debug_backtrace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) or [apd_callstack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apd-callstack.php), but that is rather inefficient and slow. [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) has a number of functions that could help you achieve this too, but all of this is nothing you want in production code.

The easiest way would be to pass the instance of B to A, e.g.

```
class A {
    protected $callerInstance;
    protected $callerClassName
    public function __construct($caller) {
        $this->callerInstance = $caller;
        $this->callerClassName = get_class($caller);
    }
}
```

Comment: I completely agree with you. Not understanding why people is voting this down.

Comment: +1 for reading the question right (and having the correct answer ofc)

Comment: again thanks for pointing out the mistake in the question. :)

Comment: I deserve a Badge for this :D

Answer (score 2):

You want [get_class()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)

> **get_class** — Returns the name of the class of an object

**edit**
As gordon said this is not possible. You might be able to parse the call stack to see what class called the one you are in, but I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you pass the name of class B to the class A constructor. That would require a modification in class A (and all classes you need this for). Hackish, but does what you need.

```
class A{
  function __construct($caller){
     echo $caller; // will echo B, C and D respectively
  }
}

class B{
   $var = new A(get_class($this));
}

class C{
   $var = new A(get_class($this));
}

class D{
   $var = new A(get_class($this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get_class($var)
```